# Kubernetes resources management best practices

Tags: kubernetes

I have a cluster where I manage namespaces on a per project basis.

Each namespace is given a resource quotas object and DevOps define usage per deployment.

A recurrent issue I face is that Kubernetes schedule pods according to a very basic sum of "used" limits against the "hard" quotas.

I could be forced to set a fairly high amount, especially in CPU, as pods need to manage bursts, but very rarely more than a couple at the same time.

If I have a 10 pods application, each with the potential to burst to 4 core, I need to define a resource quotas limit of 40 core even though it's completely unrelated to the application potential usage, even under stress.

This is specifically true as most of these project need burst to handle pods startup.

VPA could have been an answer to that, but my main concern is pod startup and VPA needs to kill pods to adjust its resource usage, so it's a bit of a deadlock.

I'm not sure what the best practices are to manage resource usage in a k8s cluster.

Obviously, my approach is falling short.

Answer (score 1):

> If I have a **10 pods** application, each with the potential to burst to **4** core, I need to define a resource quotas limit of 40 cores even though it's completely unrelated to the application potential usage, even under stress.

You don't need to define 40 cores.
In K8S you can define minimum and maximum resources for your Objects.

For example, if you wish to limit the resources to a max of 4 CPU you can still start with 0.5 CPU which means that for 10 pods you will only need 0.5*10=5CPU

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ...
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: ...
    #
    # Here we limit our Object regarding resources consuming
    # 
    resources:
      # Minimum resources for starting   
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        # m= mili, in this sample it will require 0.5CPU
        cpu: "500m"
      
      # Maximum resources consumption
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "4"
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: so will kubernetes not still say you dont have enough for this limit? Even though you start with a lower requested amount? What if in your example all pods burst to 4 CPUs at once? Will they get throttled to 500Mi because that's essentially all what's available for 5 cores? Or does Kubernetes not interfere at this moment, and they need to compete for the CPU cycles?

Comment: So it will try to spin new nodes. but you don't need 40CPU only 4

Comment: Then the applications' performance is probably impaired.  You also need auto-scaling for nodes. And it would also mean it needs to reschedule the pods somewhere else, taking it down here. I can't see how the app would operate smoothly in any case when that happens.

Comment: I agree it is clear to all that if you will try to run pods at the minimum (resources) they will not perform as best as they should be, the question was how K8S handles that and what needs to be done. And as you mentioned you should pre-allocate more nodes or at least be able to spon new nodes